# How to create a ajax callback function in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and ajaxification on Rails: 
I'm facing a problem in writing an ajax callback function.
For example, if i am writing a callback function for a delete method and write a callback code for ajax in applicaton.js, it works fine when i have written format.js to this method as

```
format.js { render :nothing => true }
```

But what i want is both: this **format.js** works and also the callback function should work.
How to do this?

Comment: Do you want to return any values from the controller side to the callback function?

Comment: for some methods i may require to return values from controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you simply try

> format.js { render :json => {} }

instead of

> format.js { render :nothing => true }

so that your callback function will be called.

Comment: will this render both(for eg delete.js) and a callback function written in application.js

Comment: What do you mean by rendering delete.js?

Comment: Mean if i'm calling a delete method and in response i'm writting a delete.js for that action. So what i want is both delete.js method should execute as well as callback function